# External monitor on Dell xps 13 9350

Tags: display, dell, external-monitor, xps

Once more some odd problems with Ubuntu on the Dell XPS 13 (9350, 2016 model). I got the Dell DA200 adapter (USB-C to HDMI/VGA/Ethernet/USB3.0) to attach an external monitor. I have tested two monitors: one has a VGA port, the other has VGA and DVI ports. Here are my test results:

```
Ubuntu, DVI-connection with screen: no display (though linux recognizes it)
Ubuntu, VGA-connection both screens: working display
Windows, DVI-connection with screen: working display
```

- Kernel: 4.6.0-040600rc7-generic
- Linux: Ubuntu 16.04
- Display manager: Gnome

Edit: the problem is not that the system doesn't work entirely. It apparently only works for certain resolutions. I currently got my screen working with 1680x1050. The standard for this monitor is 1920x1080. However, at work I have a Dell U2515H (2560x1440) and that resolution doesn't work either. I haven't tried anything between 1920x1080 and 2560x1440 yet, but I'd like any resolution to work.

Edit2: the output of `xrandr -q` is equal when the screen is set to a working resolution as when it is set to a non-working resolution. Here's the output for a non-working resolution:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      74.98    59.90  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it's a kernel bug related to i915. A bug report has been filed here https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93578 . We will need to wait for a fix.

Comment: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94567  seems also relevant